Looking for my favorite childhood movie about a man who visits his daughter after death
A man who dies just as his daughter is born and gets a grant 17 years or so later to go down to earth and help his daughter find her way, I think it was originally black and white and only but had color added - very old

Was it a musical?
Carousel is about a carnival carousel operator, Billy, who discovers he is to become a father, but is currently unemployed. A friend talks him into attempting a robbery, and Billy is accidentally killed while running from the police.
Later, he is given the chance to return to Earth for a day to help his now teenaged daughter who is struggling with being constantly reminded of her father's crime.
In the end, Billy's wife and daughter are left with a new confidence, and know that Billy loved/loves them.



